# Postgresql Master-slave replication lagged but pgpool was sending traffic to both db (master n slave)

Tags: django, postgresql, load-balancing, master-slave, pgpool

We do database load balancing using **pgpool2 framwork** (master + 1 slave).

Yesterday I got few database errors on test server saying - '**column X does not exist**'
Upon debugging we found that master-slave replication has stopped or lagged due to which **django migration was done just on master server but not on slave**. pgppol was still sending read queries to slave server.

How can I avoid such problems or **automate such that alarm is raised or notification** if anything happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using streaming mode (which is default)

```
master_slave_mode = on
                                   # Activate master/slave mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
```

You need to configure following to check replication status:

```
# - Streaming -

sr_check_period = 10
                                   # Streaming replication check period
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
sr_check_user = 'nobody'
                                   # Streaming replication check user
                                   # This is neccessary even if you disable streaming
                                   # replication delay check by sr_check_period = 0
sr_check_password = ''
                                   # Password for streaming replication check user
                                   # Leaving it empty will make Pgpool-II to first look for the
                                   # Password in pool_passwd file before using the empty password

sr_check_database = 'postgres'
                                   # Database name for streaming replication check
delay_threshold = 10000000
                                   # Threshold before not dispatching query to standby node
                                   # Unit is in bytes
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
```

Here is the documentation of this feauture:
https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-streaming-replication-check.html

Comment: That is great! But how will I get to know that due to replication lag , queries are not going to slave server? Will pgpool will raise any alarm?

Comment: If replication delay exceeds `delay_threshold`, so SELECT query will be sent to slave. You can enable logging using `log_standby_delay` with values (none, always or if_over_threshold)